# is it possible to make swiffy object start playing by skipping the first 100 frames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-swiffy

I have 100s of fla files and I do not want to manipulate them I just want to find a javascript solution to figure out how to skip the first 100 frames in my animation.

I tried to look at the SO but it seems only pause/resume option is available.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem.  The Google Swiffy runtime doesn't provide an API for going to a particular frame; however, it does allow you to setFlashVars.  You can use that to send "messages" to whatever API you create in your ActionScript.

With hundreds or thousands of animations, you'll need to automate the processing anyhow, so just mix into your build process some calls to JSFL to inject the desired ActionScript API.

Comment: thanks, I will try that out, still I will have to edit all my flash files checking with the designer if that is applicable.